# Updating how many enemies are remaining - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new to Unity and I've had a look around for similar problems, but I suck at transferring it over into my program.

Anyway, I basically have a class called `Scoring` that will keep track of how many enemies there are on the level. I want to pass this value into another class called `Bullet_explosive`. In this class, it will remove one from that total when an enemy has been hit with the bullet. After it has removed one from the total, I want this value to be passed back into `Scoring` so that it can be displayed on the screen to the player.

Probably been answered a million times, but I'm sick of not knowing how to implement it into my own program.

Thanks in advance.

Here's the `Scoring` class:

```
public class Scoring : MonoBehaviour {

// Create gameobject to store the text object within
public GameObject textObject;

// Holds the text displayed on screen
Text actualText;

// Holds the remaining number of enemies
public static int enemiesRemaining = 12;



// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    //  Stores the gameobject called EnemiesRemaining
    textObject = GameObject.Find ("EnemiesRemaining");
    // Gets the text component of that gameobject
    actualText = textObject.GetComponent<Text> ();
    // Stores what text the display will actually show
    actualText.text = "Enemies Remaining: " + enemiesRemaining;
}



// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    // Updates the display
    actualText.text = "Enemies Remaining: " + enemiesRemaining;
}
```

Here's the `Bullet_explosive` class:

```
public class Bullet_explosive : MonoBehaviour {

// Lifespan of the bullet
float lifespan = 1.5f;

// Setting up game objects
public GameObject fireEffect;
public GameObject explosion;
public GameObject theGate;

//Passing through the enemies remaining
private static int score;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{   

    score = Scoring.enemiesRemaining;


    lifespan -= Time.deltaTime;

    // Once the lifespan reaches 0, bullet is destroyed
    if (lifespan <= 0) 
    {
        Explode ();
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") 
    {
        // Reduces the remaining enemies
        score -= 1;

        // Checks for no remaining enemies
        if (score <= 0) 
        {
            // Removes the gate
            Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag ("Gate"));
        }

        // Changes the tag of the target hit
        collision.gameObject.tag = "Untagged";

        // Applies visual effects at the position and rotation of the target
        Instantiate (fireEffect, collision.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Instantiate (explosion, collision.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

        // Removes bullet and target
        Explode();
        Destroy (collision.gameObject);

    }
}

void Explode()
{
    Destroy (gameObject);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it to be too much effort to have two `static` fields that mean exactly the same thing. You should only make one field for that and always refer to that same field in the `Scoring` class.

```
public class Bullet_explosive : MonoBehaviour {

// Lifespan of the bullet
float lifespan = 1.5f;

// Setting up game objects
public GameObject fireEffect;
public GameObject explosion;
public GameObject theGate;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () { }

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{   
    /* no "score" updating needed here in Update() */    
    lifespan -= Time.deltaTime;

    // Once the lifespan reaches 0, bullet is destroyed
    if (lifespan <= 0) 
    {
        Explode ();
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") 
    {
        // Reduces the remaining enemies
        //Directly modify that one static field
        Scoring.enemiesRemaining -= 1;

        // Checks for no remaining enemies
        if (Scoring.enemiesRemaining <= 0) //here too
        {
            // Removes the gate
            Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag ("Gate"));
        }

        // Changes the tag of the target hit
        collision.gameObject.tag = "Untagged";

        // Applies visual effects at the position and rotation of the target
        Instantiate (fireEffect, collision.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Instantiate (explosion, collision.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

        // Removes bullet and target
        Explode();
        Destroy (collision.gameObject);
    }
}

void Explode()
{
    Destroy (gameObject);
}
```

And that should be it.

Comment: Also I'd recommend to only update the text field when the value actually changes. For this you would need either a function to set the score and update the text too or a property that does the same. This would also encapsulate your score value.

Comment: In the `Scoring` class you have a `Update()` method that already looks good and should update the value of `enemiesRemaining` continously. So, it should always be up-to-date. Are you sure you're modifying `Scoring.enemiesRemaining` now? It should be properly contained in that `Text` then. Place some calls in `Update()` to see it execute. You do have this script instantiated on some object, right?